# Citrix Receiver disable citrix shortcut on client side

Tags: citrix, citrix-receiver

I am using citrix receiver, and start citrix application from the web. I want to disable citrix shortcuts like Shift+F2, Shift+F3 etc., to be not interpreted by Citrix but passed to the application published in Citrix. I have found lot of tutorials(via Active directory, template profiles) but only for the Citrix administrator on Servers not for the user of the citrix receiver. How can I disable these shortcuts on my client machine that is using the citrix receiver.